# Weird unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04

I have some weird unmet dependencies i've tried everything to fix them.
Here is the output of sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 freeglut3 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                      libgl1
 gnome-session-bin : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                              libgl1
 indicator-network : Depends: unity8 (>= 7.82) but it is not going to be installed
 libcanberra-pulse : Depends: pulseaudio but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libcogl15 : Depends: libegl1-mesa-drivers
             Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5) or
                            libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic but it is not going to be installed or
                            libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
 libglamor0 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                       libgl1
 libglew1.10 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                        libgl1
 libglewmx1.10 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                          libgl1
 libgnome-desktop-3-7 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                                 libgl1
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                       libgl1
              Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) or
                       libgles2
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                         libgl1
 libsoup2.4-1 : Depends: glib-networking (>= 2.32.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) but 4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libubuntu-application-api-mirserver1 : Depends: libmirserver18 (>= 0.1.8+14.04.20140408.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libunity-mir1 : Depends: libmirserver18 (>= 0.1.8+14.04.20140411) but it is not going to be installed
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 (= 2.4.8-1ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libenchant1c2a (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                               libgl1
                      Depends: libharfbuzz-icu0 (>= 0.9.18) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good but it is not going to be installed
 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 (= 2.4.8-1ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libenchant1c2a (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                               libgl1
                      Depends: libharfbuzz-icu0 (>= 0.9.18) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good but it is not going to be installed
 nux-tools : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                      libgl1
 system-config-printer-gnome : Depends: packagekit-system-interface
 x11-utils : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                      libgl1
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Internal error, Upgrade broke stuff
```

For example the first one freeglut3 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or libgl1
I already have libgl1-mesa-glx installed. i'm pretty sure i have all of the dependencies installed but it says they aren't. I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install package from a newer repo but that doesn't have access to a repo with the newer dependencies.Edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

heres an example of /etc/apt/sources.list file
also goto Software and Updates from unity and remove non critical repos 
then do a

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I strongly suggest eliminating repositories of different versions from your sources.list -- as others have already said, it's a recipe for a broken system (with a preferences file, you can manage some mixing, usually it's good practice just to avoid mixing versions).